# Why does CiviDiscount remove the url parameters after a discount code is applied?

Tags: cividiscount

A typical event URL looks like this:

- https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=3

But when you apply a discount code, the page is refreshed and the url parameters are removed:

- https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/register

This can lead to unexpected behavior when your url contains e.g. lcMessages, to force civi in a specific language.

Does anyone know why CiviDiscount removes these query parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form submissions will always remove the parameters because they are now in $_POST and for example keeping "reset=1" would mean the form would reset and wouldn't get processed fully. So not just cividiscount. Some forms redirect to a different url and might add some parameters but that's specific to the form.

lcMessages is a bit special and yes maybe it needs some extra handling.